# Unity - Input System does not work in built game but does work in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity's new(ish) input system - package v1.4.4 (release) with Unity 2021.3.12f which works fine in editor mode but not at all in build mode. There are no errors or crashes - just no response to mouse, keyboard, gamepad or joystick when using the built exe. I've exhausted the first 3 pages of Google trying to find a solution and I'm looking for any more ideas.

Things I've tried:

- The 1.5.0 beta version of the package
- Changing manifest.json
- Reinstalling the package
- Building 32 bit only
- Changing input mode to 'both' and 'new' in project settings
- Using an input system asset triggering events rather than instantiating a version of the auto generated class
  ('com.unity.inputsystem:InputActionCodeGenerator')
- Regenerating the above file
- Rebuilding the project

Here's a code snippet:

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class MainCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    CityInput cityInput; // my input asset auto generated class
    
    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (cityInput == null) cityInput = new CityInput();
        cityInput.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        cityInput.Disable();
    }

    void Update()
    {
    // stuff....
    moveDirection = cityInput.Player.MoveDirection.ReadValue<Vector2>().normalized;
    // stuff....
    }

}
```

Relevant docs / pages:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-input-system-doesnt-work-on-build.1188934/

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183243/unitys-new-input-system-does-not-work-after-building-the-game

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HowDoI.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Actions.html#creating-actions

To recreate the setup (MCVE):

- Install 'Input System' 1.4.4 from the Package Manager.
- Create a new input asset detailing what keys / buttons relate to what names actions you want e.g. left / right / up / jump etc. See the docs.
- Generate the required C# using Unity's auto-generator script as linked above by clicking on the asset and using the 'generate c#' toggle and apply button.
- Add the using UnityEngine.InputSystem directive to a script.
- Instantiate a copy of your auto-generated script in OnEnable or OnAwake.
- Use the new methods from UnityEngine.InputSystem as per the code snippet above and the linked docs. e.g. yourAutoGeneratedInputScript.Player.MoveDirection.ReadValue().
- Build and run a scene containing your movement script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to using player prefs to store things like movement speed - they have different storage locations in a built game vs the editor: [player prefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)